# Cannot create a flutter app using flutter create

Tags: flutter

When i run flutter create I get[image]

Im not sure why that png is a sticking point everything above it are in the same parent folders. Has anyone run into this issue?The Programming Flutter folder seems like it is being set as read only:
[image]

But when i uncheck the Read only box and click apply when i open it again its set to Read Only again. But thats the very parent folder and other files seem to copy across fine before the error above.

Anyone have any idea why its failing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently updated your Flutter version, or are you running on an older version? As per [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50880), it seems to have been fixed somewhere in 2020.

Comment: I just took the very latest version of flutter. It seems it was my anti virus stopping it

Answer (score 0):

It is your operating system not allowing Flutter to write files.
You can either delete that folder and create that again or change permissions. Uncheck that 'read-only' checkbox shown in picture.
You can learn more about handling permissions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-permissions-mysteriously-set-to-read-only/3762489b-93e4-4df9-a87c-13d850adba47).